# MS GRAPH API: Getting Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderExecption while trying to call Reports method

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, console-application

I'm trying to write logic that will extract some user reports.  Specifically I'd like to be able to see a particular user's Team's Activity..

```
    static async GetReports()
    {
        graphServiceClient = await CreateGraphClient();
        var report = await graphServiceClient.Reports
            .GetOneDriveActivityUserDetail("D7")
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
           Console.WriteLine(report.ToString());


    /*
        var directoryAudits = await graphServiceClient.AuditLogs.DirectoryAudits
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(directoryAudits);
    */

    }

   static async Task Main()
    {
       await GetReports();

    }
```

But when I do, I get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: R. Path '', line 0, position 0.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Graph.Serializer.DeserializeObject[T](String inputString)
   at Microsoft.Graph.ResponseHandler.HandleResponse[T](HttpResponseMessage response)
   at Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.SendAsync[T](Object serializableObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken, HttpCompletionOption completionOption)
   at QueueApp.Program.GetReports() in /Volumes/X8/src/demos/storageaccount/Program.cs:line 215
   at QueueApp.Program.Main() in /Volumes/X8/src/demos/storageaccount/Program.cs:line 275
   at QueueApp.Program.<Main>()
```

I don't understand why it's trying to call this particular library.
line 215 is the line where I declare the report variable....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug in SDK. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getonedriveactivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0), the report returns CSV, so probably that's the reason why the request fails.

As a workaround, you can try to send http request and read the content from the response.

```
// create a get request
var request = graphServiceClient.Reports
            .GetOneDriveActivityUserDetail("D7")
            .Request()
            .GetHttpRequestMessage();

// send the request to get the response
var response = await graphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(request);
string csvReport = "";
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // read the report
    csvReport = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
else
{
    // read the error status code and error message
    var code = response.StatusCode.ToString();
    var message = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```